# KSP Flight Menu won't appear(64X windows 8)

Tags: kerbal-space-program, windows-8

Yeah, it was working a while ago, but ever since my dad decided to install 7 different anti viruses it stopped. Normally, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> while in flight or doing a science report replies with a menu appearing. (I'm running modded by the way, but even without mods it doesn't appear, and the mod menus, such as the hangar mod's menu to deploy things works properly, no issues). I need some help on this. Its similiar to the KSP flight menu not appearing in Windows 10, but my computer probably won't work that way. Anyways, thanks for any help.

Comment: You should get your dad to have a read of [this question over on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/52643).

Comment: Having more than one anti-virus is never a good idea. They can fight against each other, each thinking the other is a virus and quarantining parts of the other program, causing issues with resources. Find one that is the best, and remove the others. (Or rather convince your Dad to do it) Kaspersky is a trusted source, so you can provide [this link](https://blog.kaspersky.com/multiple-antivirus-programs-bad-idea/)

Comment: I forgot about this problem I had. Anyways, I fixed it(I needed to run it in admin, 256 colors for whatever reason my PC decided, and in compatibility mode.)